# Use custom function (Median Absolute Deviation) in Pandas `transform()`

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe for which I want to compute the MEDIAN Absolute Deviation by cluster. I assumed that the pandas method `mad` was the Median Absolute Deviation, but it appears that it is the MEAN Absolute Deviation. The line of code i have written is

```
df['MAD PPGamp'] = df.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].transform('mad')
```

I tried to write a little function of my own to compute the Median Absolute Deviation

```
def myMAD(x):
    med = np.median(x)
    x   = abs(x-med)
    MAD = np.median(x)
    return MAD
```

and to change my code to read

```
df['MAD PPGamp'] = df.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].transform('myMAD')
```

Unfortunately this does doesn't work. I get an AttributeError 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'myMAD".

How can I compute the Median Absolute deviations by cluster for  a column in my dataframe and create a new column with the MAD broadcast across rows correctly using transform?

Thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: I suggest using the already implemented scipy.stats.median_absolute_deviation

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example.

Answer (score 3):

You are close, need `myMAD` instead `'myMAD'` because your custom function:

```
df['MAD PPGamp'] = df.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].transform(myMAD)
```

EDIT:

Your solution is possible without helper column with grouping by column `df['Cluster']`:

```
s1 = df.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].transform('median')
s2 = df['PPGamp'].sub(s1).abs()

df['MAD PPGamp'] = s2.groupby(df['Cluster']).transform('median')
```

Comment: Thanks  a mill - i missed seeing this as i wrote up my two step solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a two step solution to my problem:

```
df['Abs Delta PPGamp']  = abs(df['PPGamp'] - df['Med PPGamp'])
df['MAD PPGamp'] = df.groupby('Cluster')['Abs Delta PPGamp'].transform('median')
```

May I then restate my question as: How can I apply any (reasonable) user defined (or even internal to Python) function to a column of a dataframe when using groupby.

Answer (score 0):

You where almost there.

**TL;DR version: one solution is to run**

```
df_test['MAD PPGamp'] = df_test.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].transform(myMAD)
```

**Longer answer**
Working up a MWE

Your MAD function is defined correct.

```
def myMAD(x):
    med = np.median(x)
    x   = abs(x-med)
    MAD = np.median(x)
    return MAD
```

I am just using a shorter one below, the full MWE to get what you want would be something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

get_mad = lambda x: np.median( np.abs(x - np.median(x)))
np.random.seed(1)

df_test = pd.DataFrame(dict(Cluster=np.random.randint(2, size=10), PPGamp=np.random.rand(10,)))

df_test['MAD PPGamp'] = df_test.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].transform(get_mad)
```

This is basically equivalent to doing

```
df_results = df_test.groupby('Cluster')['PPGamp'].apply(get_mad)  
df_test['MAD PPGamp'] = df_test.Cluster.map(df_results.to_dict())
```

**Please provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE) when asking questions next time.**