# How to include columns with highest median absolute deviation in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 20,000 columns and 1,000 rows. Each column has a title and about a thousand rows of numbers between 0 and 1.

How do I make a new dataframe with the 2000 columns with the highest median absolute deviations?

Comment: What is a "median absolute deviation"?

Comment: @topsail: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation

Comment: related: [Use custom function (Median Absolute Deviation) in Pandas `transform()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61436389/12846804) - [Where can I find mad (mean absolute deviation) in scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8930370/12846804)

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the [median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation) with Pandas:

```
mad = df.sub(df.median()).abs().median()
cols = mad.sort_values(ascending=False).head(1000).index
out = df[cols]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        4482      7833      10371     3059   ...     3509      1381      16339     13624
0    0.402850  0.343102  0.031398  0.512106  ...  0.243998  0.545462  0.607359  0.045264
1    0.166466  0.421302  0.763680  0.470844  ...  0.974354  0.719405  0.063957  0.206610
2    0.110333  0.384587  0.605379  0.700797  ...  0.440506  0.080930  0.795212  0.739654
3    0.796290  0.111921  0.006973  0.032487  ...  0.635054  0.084994  0.880535  0.953851
4    0.292507  0.397712  0.077202  0.344962  ...  0.096461  0.541819  0.640090  0.328734
..        ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
995  0.750768  0.003682  0.888703  0.489006  ...  0.193343  0.657994  0.160474  0.813851
996  0.618256  0.148921  0.341706  0.666733  ...  0.987573  0.912837  0.228429  0.820677
997  0.750872  0.107276  0.826156  0.444998  ...  0.806361  0.426168  0.403077  0.506427
998  0.357668  0.534283  0.823693  0.862560  ...  0.265828  0.733393  0.181072  0.843684
999  0.014925  0.876978  0.857382  0.339644  ...  0.671423  0.662551  0.381922  0.936142

[1000 rows x 1000 columns]  # 1000 columns with the highest MAD
```

Minimal Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=2024)
df = pd.DataFrame(rng.random((1000, 20000)))
print(df)

# Output
        0         1         2         3      ...     19996     19997     19998     19999
0    0.675831  0.214323  0.309452  0.799466  ...  0.876652  0.417957  0.302618  0.033723
1    0.165503  0.609271  0.840614  0.850995  ...  0.691652  0.327852  0.802473  0.680307
2    0.072913  0.244916  0.382106  0.403751  ...  0.310791  0.631182  0.103423  0.449572
3    0.430460  0.434423  0.130567  0.626203  ...  0.192436  0.017470  0.723502  0.482124
4    0.841660  0.838981  0.018308  0.298541  ...  0.347722  0.914452  0.551496  0.559643
..        ...       ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
995  0.681365  0.749116  0.517394  0.244040  ...  0.822666  0.024155  0.861577  0.287123
996  0.281651  0.261294  0.040658  0.199055  ...  0.814796  0.649532  0.281308  0.285338
997  0.222746  0.037439  0.970851  0.099662  ...  0.832852  0.927674  0.836475  0.795975
998  0.045993  0.606851  0.805329  0.391254  ...  0.693919  0.232225  0.139263  0.755060
999  0.609697  0.572186  0.006462  0.749773  ...  0.150595  0.523282  0.705894  0.047099

[1000 rows x 20000 columns]
```